# ASP.NET MVC DataBinder not deserializing simple types from JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, data-binding, deserialization

Input JSON:

```
{ "name": "gerry" }
```

Action method:

```
{ public ActionResult GenerateQrCode([FromBody] string name }
```

Problem:

- The simple-type args are null
- ModelState: Invalid
- The built-in json deserializer can't handle the input in this form

I've tried:

- `ConfigureServices()` -> `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();` to switch to NewtonSoft, which I know/love
- I've set a break-point into the non-NewtonSoft built-in MS `SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ctor()` just to check, if it's still used: yes, it is, I'm not sure why, when I'm calling the above `.AddNewtonsoftJson()`

The situation:

- The client POSTs all the input params as one JSON string document, which is UTF8 w/out BOM
- The string comes in at the server-side and is nicely readable with `new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd()` from inside the immediate window
- I need a way ASP.NET Core deserializes this, as it was able under the .NET4.X for many years w/out any issue
- I wouldn't like to add `[FromBody]` and similar opt-in signatures all over the server actions/args

Answer (score 0):

You pass the name as json but accept as a string so it will be null, you can use an InputFormatter like:

```
public class RawJsonBodyInputFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public RawJsonBodyInputFormatter()
    {
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/json");
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
        }
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

In startup.cs:

```
services
.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new RawJsonBodyInputFormatter());
});
```

And then you can get the row string

[image]

To deserilize it, you can check this, use Newtonsoft and make the string to a Model

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GenerateQrCode([FromBody] string name)
    {
        object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(name);
        MyModel my = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(o.ToString());
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but:
- I need to accept MANY args, not just 1 string
- I need the custom formatter to be used to all the args, not just to one [FromBody] argument

I POST a JSON doc in the body payload and expect the input formatter to read all the named args from the one valid/usual JSON doc, like:

application/json: { "param1": "hello", "param2": "world", "param3": true, "param4": 1974 }
i-face: Foo(string param1, string param2, bool param3, int param4) { }